# explain how this jquery ajax passes data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following class in a php file:

```
function calcTotal(){
        var productID = <?php echo $product_info['products_id'];?>;
    var sizeID = 0; 

    $(".mine_sizes").each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked'))  sizeID = $(this).val();                         
     });
    //alert(sizeID);
    var colorID = 0;

    $(".mine_color").each(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked'))  colorID = $(this).val();                        
     });

     $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'get_product_price.php',
              data: "product_id="+ productID +"&color_id="+ colorID +"&size_id="+ sizeID,
              success: function( response ) {       
                    $("#price_container").html(response);
                    ;

              } 

     });

}
```

and the php file get_product_price.php:

```
if($_POST){

     $product_info_query = tep_db_query("select products_price, products_tax_class_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "  where products_id = '" . (int)$_POST['product_id']."'");
     $pricePrice = tep_db_fetch_array($product_info_query);
     $productPrice = $pricePrice['products_price'];

    $sizesPrices = tep_db_query("select options_values_price from products_attributes   where products_id='".$_POST['product_id']."' and options_values_id='".$_POST['size_id']."'");
 //  echo "select options_values_price from products_attributes   where products_id='".$_POST['product_id']."' and options_values_id='".$_POST['size_id']."'";
  // exit;
    if(mysql_num_rows($sizesPrices)>0){
        $priceRow = tep_db_fetch_array($sizesPrices);
        $productPrice = $productPrice + $priceRow['options_values_price'];
    }

    $sizesPrices2 = tep_db_query("select price from product_attributes_color_relation   where product_id='".$_POST['product_id']."' and color_id='".$_POST['color_id']."' and color_size_option_id='".$_POST['size_id']."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($sizesPrices2)>0){
        $priceRow2 = tep_db_fetch_array($sizesPrices2);
        $productPrice = $productPrice + $priceRow2['price'];
    }
    //echo $productPrice; exit;
    echo $currencies->display_price($productPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($product_info['products_tax_class_id']));
    //echo $productPrice;
}
```

The function is called on a radio button click and is currently working but I am trying to understand how it works for myself (and to possibly recreate a similar function)

What I am not really understanding is the data parameter from the ajax api. How is that data parameter used?

another question I have is the success parameter. Is the "response" parameter a standard or can in be called anything?

Thanks for any help explaining this to me. I don't think any other information is necessary, there is a div with a class id #price_container which is where the price is echo'd.

Comment: It's sent over to the server like this -> `get_product_price.php?product_id="+ productID +"&color_id="+ colorID +"&size_id="+ sizeID`. You pick it apart by referencing the `type (which in your case, is POST)`.

Comment: Also, the `success` paramter is the same as `response 200 OK`. If the response is `not 200 ok`, the `success parameter` will never fire. [Many, if not ALL your questions can be answered by reading the docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data parameter passes the information the same way an HTML form will.  At least that's the easiest way to think of it.  So that "data" will come through as $_POST or $_GET arrays.  I always setup my data as JSON format:

```
data: { "product_id": productID,"color_id": colorID, "size_id": sizeID },
```

With your type set as "POST" that would come through as:

```
$_POST['product_id']
$_POST['color_id']
$_POST['size_id']
```

You can specify any variable name for the response - but 'response' is nice and easy to remember and work with.  :)

Comment: Thanks, And thank you ohgodwhy that helped me understand a little.

Answer (score 1):

from the ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

`data`

> [Object, String] 
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a
>   query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for
>   GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic
>   processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array,
>   jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of
>   the traditional setting (described below).

Basically if you set the `data` variable to a query string, it sends it to the server as is, other wise it will generate a query string from the key value pairs that you set. Once the php server receives the query string it is parsed and you can access your values using
`$_POST['key']`